# revolution slider custom function trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

I don't know JQuery but I can do basic JavaScript. I need to trigger and control a layer in Revolution Slider.
Below is the Event handler function provided by the slider.

```
revapi18.bind("revolution.slide.layeraction",function (e) {
//data.eventtype - Layer Action (enterstage, enteredstage, leavestage,leftstage)
//data.layertype - Layer Type (image,video,html)
//data.layersettings - Default Settings for Layer
//data.layer - Layer as jQuery Object
});
```

How can I have an alert message to pop up when the layer has left the stage (leavestage)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `leftstage` since you say the alert should happen after the layer has left. I'm guessing `leavestage` happens before the slide leaves. From [their code](http://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/api/), it looks like it would be:

```
jQuery('#slideid').bind("revolution.slide.leftstage",function (e) {
    alert('left');
});
```